# what is the logic for retry the request when http response message is 502

Tags: performance, jmeter

During my load testing in some of the request i am getting 403 and 502 error code . I want to retry those request which are failed due to these status code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${statusCode}" != "200",)}
   ```
2. Add the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of your request and configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, the request will be repeated until you get HTTP Status code `200`

Comment: Hi @Dmitri .There is one issue i am facing .When we are uploading near around 5GB of   data from web UI it is taking only 15 to 20 minutes . The similar data if i am  uploading through HTTP request it is taking more than 2 hour. How can i achieve  the same performance